# How would I mirror Firebase database to local indexedDB for offline use in a React app?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, redux, indexeddb

I'm building a Progressive webapp which is designed to be offline first. I have already used service worker to cache the static app shell but for database data retrieved from firebase database , I can't seem to figure out how to cache it for offline use that persists on hard reset. There is [this polymer element](https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-storage) that does is but I need a solution that I can use with React. By the way I'm using Redux, so would [Redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) achieve the same goal?

**Update:** Redux-persist npm module does exactly this.